# ASP.Net Vertical Menu with Scroll functionality

Tags: asp.net, menu, scroll

Referring to [Menu / Scrolling Example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/functionality/scrolling/defaultcs.aspx)

I would like to create / find the same functionality for a vertical menu. I tried the following.

```
    <asp:Menu ID="menuAccountMembers" runat="server" StaticSubMenuIndent="16px" 
        Visible="true" RenderingMode="Table"
        ScrollDownImageUrl="~/Resources/scrolldown.jpg" 
        ScrollUpImageUrl="~/Resources/scrollup.jpg">
        <Items>
```

But it doesnt display any scrolling images. I am using .net 4.0
Tried setting **menuAccountMembers.RenderingCompatibility = new Version(3, 5);** as well.

If there a property to only display the first 5 root menu items, then show scroll bars for the rest? It can be click-able, no need to hover over to show next item.

Comment: Found something pretty close http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html

Comment: But I would obviously prefer to create it using the menu control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Jcarousel sufficient